# Implementing the matlab find function

Tags: matlab, find

I am trying to find the coordinates of all non zero elements in a matrix, in MATLAB. I know that `find` makes this very easy. The problem is that I need to define the length of my matrix before I can fill it up. I believe this is impossible using `find`, since it will make its own vector.

So I have to find another way. If I'm looking for 1 element it will be easy as well. Let me use an example. Say I have a matrix `M` of 500×500, with `60` ones somewhere. I want to find the coordinates. So I can start with:

```
for i = 1:500
  for j = 1:500
    if M(i,j) == 1
       row = i;
       col = j;
    end
  end
end
```

But I want more then one point, and I need to define the length of a vector before filling it. So I'll make the gamble that there are less then 100 ones in the matrix:

```
v = zeros(1,100)
w = zeros(1,100)
```

And how I essentially want to fill this vector is as follows. Let's say I have already filled `N` elements of the vector, so the next one will be:

```
for i = 1:500
  for j = 1:500
    if M(i,j) == 1 && i ~= v(1) && i ~= v(2) && ... && i ~= v(N) && j ~= v(1) && ... && i ~= v(N)
     v(N+1) = i
     w(N+1) = j
    end
  end
end
```

So I need another for loop containing all this, which will run through the elements of the vectors `v` and `w`, and I need some loop that will make sure the right if statement is being used.

Does anyone have any idea of how to do this?

Kind regards,

Jesse

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, do you know you can specify how many elements you want find to return as a parameter?

Comment: Sound like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me...Please explain what you want to achieve in the end, rather than ask questions about problems you encountered during your attempts to achieve it.

Comment: You know your second implementation is incorrect right? That one will not find all 1's correctly. Moreover, if you'd do it correctly, `[v w]` will be equal to `[v2 w2] = find(M)`...I'm just not sure what you're getting at here...

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way, nice & wasteful:

```
[jj,ii] = meshgrid(1:size(M,2),1:size(M,1));        
inds = M~=0;
ii   = ii(inds);
jj   = jj(inds);
```

Comment: I don't know what to say. Is using logical indexing instead of `find` is "cheating"?

Comment: @Shai: ... I feel dirty ... :p

Answer (score 2):

I honestly cannot understand what's wrong with `find`.
But, if you insist on your own implementation using nested loop, then

```
v = NaN(100,1);
w = NaN(100,1); % pre-allocate
ii=1;
for row=1:size(M,1)
    for col=1:size(M,2)
        if M(row,col) == 1
           v(ii)=row;
           w(ii)=col;
           ii=ii+1; %counts howmany elements were found
        end
    end
end
v(isnan(v))=[]; %discard redundent elements
w(isnan(w))=[];
```